# Apache does not update environment variables

Tags: php, apache, centos, env

I have changed the ORACLE_HOME environment variable and I can see the new value in command line (using the echo command). However, even after restarting apache I see the old value on phpinfo() output "Environment" part yet. What is wrong with it? Is it cached? How to refresh that? – PHPst 57 secs ago   edit

Answer (score 0):

Apache knows nothing about your command line.

Define environment variables in apache [config](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_env.html#setenv):

```
SetEnv ORACLE_HOME /home/oracle/or/whatever/value/you/need
```